# How can I write separate log files in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

I'd like to have separate log files to store debug data for some of my API methods. Something like `car_create.log`, `car_update.log`, etc.

Can I achieve this with the built-in logging functionality? Isn't it some kind of wrong approach? Because it seems like almost nobody have same issues. Any advice or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Laravel uses `Monolog` which would allow you to do this. Check `https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, separate log files are possible.

The [Errors & Logging documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#introduction) informs that [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md) is the underlying logging package used by Laravel. You can use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md) to do anything you want.

### Example Logging Helper

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Common;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class FileLogger extends Logger
{
    protected $path = null;

    public function __construct($name, $level = 'DEBUG', $path = null, array $processors = [ ])
    {
        $tz = static::$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(config('app.timezone'));
        $handlers = [ ];
        parent::__construct($name, $handlers, $processors);

        $dtObj = Carbon::now($tz);

        if ( ! $path) {
            $path = $name . '-' . $dtObj->format('Y-m-d') . '.log';
        }

        $path = $this->path = storage_path('logs/' . $path);

        $this->addStream($path, $level);

        return $this;
    }

    public static function getLevelNum($level)
    {
        return static::getLevels()[ strtoupper($level) ];
    }

    public function addStream($path, $level = 'DEBUG')
    {
        if ( ! is_int($level)) {
            $level = static::getLevelNum($level);
        }
        $this->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($path, $level));

        return $this;
    }

    public function addRecord($level, $message, array $context = array())
    {
        if ( ! is_int($level)) {
            $level = static::getLevelNum($level);
        }

        parent::addRecord($level, $message, $context);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### Example Usage

```
use App\Helpers\Common\FileLogger;

// ...

$level = 'DEBUG';

$logger = new FileLogger('NAME', $level);

$logger->addRecord($level, $message, $context);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely what I want!